# (x86 MASM Intel) Need explain in my assembly code for bubble sort

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, bubble-sort

so I have my assembly code for bubble sort but not quite sure how mov edx,0 and mov ebp, 0 contributes to my program, I just randomly test and it works but idk why, hope you  guys can help

```
.686
.model flat

.code

_sort PROC

    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp             ; stack pointer to ebp
    
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]        ; address of first array element
    mov ecx, [ebp+12]       ; size of the array
    mov edx, [ebp+16]       ; (0 for ascending and 1 for descending)

    dec ecx                 ; ecx = size - 1
    mov eax, 0              ; i = 0
    cmp edx, 0              ; compare type of sort with 0 
    je AscenOuterLoop       ; if it's 0 then do ascending sort
    jg DescenOuterLoop      ; if it's 1 then do descending sort
    
AscenOuterLoop: 
    cmp eax, ecx            ; compare eax and ecx
    je Done                 ; loop till the end of array
    add eax, 1              ; i++
    mov edx, 0               
    mov ebp, 0              

DescenOuterLoop:    
    cmp eax, ecx            ; compare i and size - 1
    je Done                 ; i = size - 1, we finish
    add eax, 1              ; i++
    mov edx, 0              
    mov ebp, 0              

AscenInnerLoop:
    cmp ebp, ecx            ; compare j and size - 1
    je AscenOuterLoop           ; j = size - 1, exit the inner loop
    mov esi,[ebx+edx]       ; esi = a[j]
    cmp esi, [ebx+edx+4]    ; compare a[j] and a[j+1]
    jg AscSwapElements      ; if a[j] > a[j+1], swap a[j], and a[j+1]
    jmp AscIncreaseIndex    ; if a[j] <= a[j+1], do nothing, increase index

AscSwapElements:            
    mov edi, [ebx+edx+4]    ; edi = a[j+1]
    mov [ebx+edx], edi      ; a[j] = edi = a[j+1]
    mov [ebx+edx+4], esi    ; a[j+1] = esi = a[j]       

AscIncreaseIndex:
    inc ebp                 ; j++
    add edx, 4              ; increase the index in byte by 4
    jmp AscInnerLoop        ; continue inner loop


DesInnerLoop:
    cmp ebp, ecx            ; compare j and size - 1
    je DescenOuterLoop          ; j = size - 1, exit the inner loop
    mov esi,[ebx+edx]       ; esi = a[j]
    cmp esi, [ebx+edx+4]    ; compare a[j] and a[j+1]
    jl DesSwapElements      ; if a[j] < a[j+1], swap a[j], and a[j+1]
    jmp DesIncreaseIndex    ; if a[j] >= a[j+1], do nothing, increase index

DesSwapElements:            
    mov edi, [ebx+edx+4]    ; edi = a[j+1]
    mov [ebx+edx], edi      ; a[j] = edi = a[j+1]
    mov [ebx+edx+4], esi    ; a[j+1] = esi = a[j]           

DesIncreaseIndex:
    inc ebp                 ; j++
    add edx, 4              ; increase the index in byte by 4
    jmp DesInnerLoop        ; continue inner loop

Done:   
    pop ebp
    ret

_sort ENDP

END
```

I think that edx and ebp is the address for i,j value just like the [] would do, but don't know they contribute to make the sort work.

Comment: Did you consider commenting them out to see what happens if they're not there?

Comment: The whole block after `AscenOuterLoop` is pointless because it just falls through to `DescenOuterLoop` which does the same things.  (Or it jumps to the end and returns).  But I think that's because it's supposed to be somewhere else, and they're not both supposed to run.  Actually, doing `add eax,1` twice isn't "pointless", it's probably just wrong.

Comment: Anyway, the commented code for the loop body makes it clear that `edx` is `j`, and obviously you have to reset the inner-loop counter / array position every time through the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that `edx` and `ebp` is the address for i,j value just like the [] would do, but don't know they contribute to make the sort work.

The OuterLoop counter *i* is in the `EAX` register.
The InnerLoop counter *j* is in the `EBP` register.

At every start of the InnerLoop, its associated counter *j* is reset with `mov ebp, 0`.

Because the array holds **dword**-sized elements, an offset variable was introduced so as to be able to address the dword elements of the array. This variable also gets reset at every start of the InnerLoop with `mov edx, 0`.

---

A nice thing about the x86 instruction set is that you don't need that separate offset variable to fetch the array elements. You can address the array elements right from the loop control variable (`EBP`) if you use a scaled-index addressing mode.

This is the ascending version with a scaled-indexing address mode and using `EDX` as the InnerLoop counter *j*:

```
AscOuterLoop: 
    cmp eax, ecx            ; compare eax and ecx
    je  Done                ; loop till the end of array
    add eax, 1              ; i++
    mov edx, 0              ; j = 0

AscInnerLoop:
    cmp edx, ecx            ; compare j and size - 1
    je  AscOuterLoop        ; j = size - 1, exit the inner loop
    mov esi,[ebx+edx*4]     ; esi = a[j]
    mov edi, [ebx+edx*4+4]  ; edi = a[j+1]
    cmp esi, edi            ; compare a[j] and a[j+1]
    jng AscIncreaseIndex    ; if a[j] <= a[j+1], do nothing, increase index
AscSwapElements:            ; if a[j] > a[j+1], swap a[j], and a[j+1]
    mov [ebx+edx*4], edi    ; a[j] = edi = a[j+1]
    mov [ebx+edx*4+4], esi  ; a[j+1] = esi = a[j]       
AscIncreaseIndex:
    inc edx                 ; j++
    jmp AscInnerLoop        ; continue inner loop
```

---

Your code is broken in 2 ways:

- You need to separate the ascending and descending versions completely. You can't let your 2 OuterLoops fall into each other!
- You keep comparing all the elements of the array each time through the OuterLoop. The idea behind BubbleSort is that after the 1st iteration of the OuterLoop, the biggest/smallest number is at the far edge of the array and that you no longer have to process that array element.
  With each iteration of the OuterLoop, the number of iterations in the InnerLoop should decrease by 1.

You can easily solve both problems:

```
    ...
    mov  ecx, [ebp+12]      ; size of the array
    mov  edx, [ebp+16]      ; (0 for ascending and 1 for descending)
    test edx, edx           ; compare type of sort with 0 
    jnz  DesOuterLoop       ; if it's NOT 0 then do descending sort
AscOuterLoop: 
    sub  ecx, 1             ; size - 1
    jbe  Done               ; loop till the end of array
    xor  edx, edx           ; j = 0
AscInnerLoop:
    ...

DesOuterLoop:
    sub  ecx, 1             ; size - 1
    jbe  Done               ; loop till the end of array
    xor  edx, edx           ; j = 0
DecInnerLoop:
    ...
```