# Array Bubble Sort in Assembly Language

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, bubble-sort

**Problem is that why is only sorting the last element and then putting 5 on every index?**

I am posting for the first time so I apologize if my question is unclear.

```
arr BYTE 5,4,3,2,1  
arr1 BYTE 5 DUP(?)  
temp BYTE ?  
.code  
main PROC   
mov ecx,LENGTHOF arr    
mov esi,Offset arr  
mov edi,offset arr+1  
L1:
mov al,[esi]  
mov edx,ecx  
mov ecx,4  
    L2:
    mov bl,[edi]  
    cmp al,bl  
    JG L3  
    jmp L5  

    L3:
    mov temp,al
    mov [esi],bl
    ;mov dl,temp
    mov [edi],al
    inc edi
    L5:
    loop L2

    mov ecx,edx
    inc esi

loop L1

;Printing my array
mov ecx,LENGTHOF arr  
mov al,arr[0]  
CALL dumpRegs  
mov al,arr[1]  
CALL dumpRegs  
mov al,arr[2]  
CALL dumpRegs  
mov al,arr[3]  
CALL dumpRegs  

CALL dumpRegs
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Get inspired by looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084399/x86-masm-intel-need-explain-in-my-assembly-code-for-bubble-sort/65096559#65096559)

Answer (score 2):

> **Problem is that why is only sorting the last element and then putting 5 on every index?**

Your *L2* InnerLoop works exclusively with the 1st array element since, once it is loaded in `AL`, you don't advance the pointer in `ESI`. And because this particular value happens to be the greatest value in the array, it gets stored everywhere.
Your *L2* InnerLoop also works with a fixed count of 4 where it should be working with a count of `CurrentOuterLoopCount - 1`.

The correct solution does not need the 2 different pointer registers. The array elements that are to be compared are always adjacent to each other and so a simple offset of +1 will do the trick.

This is a working BubbleSort. Find out how it works, don't just copy it!

```
arr BYTE 5,4,3,2,1

.code
main PROC
  mov  ecx, LENGTHOF arr
  sub  ecx, 1
  jbe  Done               ; Array is empty or has but 1 element

OuterLoop:
  mov  edx, ecx           ; 5 elements means 4 comparisons
  mov  esi, Offset arr
InnerLoop:
  mov  al, [esi]
  mov  bl, [esi+1]
  cmp  al, bl
  jng  NoSwap
  mov  [esi], bl
  mov  [esi+1], al
NoSwap:
  inc  esi
  dec  edx
  jnz  InnerLoop
  dec  ecx                ; Next time 3 comparisons, then 2, and then 1
  jnz  OuterLoop

Done:
```