# Pointer in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, swap, bubble-sort

In the swap function I passed the address of two elements that are supposed to swap. The initial array is 5,1,4,2,8
the code should perform bubble sort

```
Implement Bubble sort in assembly. Follow the reference C code and translate it to assembly. The implementation requires you exact translation of the reference code, which means you need to implement using local variables, function calls, and parameter passing following the given c code. Submit the source code, screenshot of intermediate steps, and the sorted array in memory window.

Bubble sort, sometimes referred to as sinking sort, is a simple sorting algorithm Links to an external site. that repeatedly steps through the input list element by element, comparing the current element with the one after it, swapping Links to an external site.their values if needed. These passes through the list are repeated until no swaps have to be performed during a pass, meaning that the list has become fully sorted. The algorithm, which is a comparison sort Links to an external site., is named for the way the larger elements "bubble" up to the top of the list.

 

// C program for implementation of Bubble sort
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[] = { 5, 1, 4, 2, 8 };

void swap(int* xp, int* yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

// A function to implement bubble sort
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)

        // Last i elements are already in place
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    bubbleSort(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my assembly code so far:

```
elementswap proc
push ebp
mov ebp,esp

     push eax
     push ebx
        
        ;do swap
    mov eax,[EBP+8] 
    mov ebx,[EBP+12]
    mov [EBP+8],ebx
    mov [EBP+12],eax
    
    pop eax
    pop ebx
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

elementswap endp

bubblesort proc
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
mov esi,0

    outerloop:
         mov edx,[EBP+12]
         mov ebx,[EBP+8]
         sub ebx,2
         mov ecx,ebx
         cmp esi,ebx; 0 1 2 3 4,4
         JE exit_loop
         sub ecx,esi
         mov edi,0
         JL innerloop
    
    innerloop:
         cmp edi,ecx ;0 1 2 3 4,4 ;0 1 2 3,3;0 1 2,2;0 1,1;0,0
         JE L3
         JL L1
    
    L1:
        mov eax,[edx]
        add edx,4
        cmp eax,[edx]; 5,1   5,4   5,2 ;  1 4 2 5 8; 1,4 4,2 4,5 8; 1 2 4 5 8
        JG eleswap ;if eax content is bigger than element of the address stored edx
        JLE L2 ;if eax is less or equal than element of the address stored edx
    
    eleswap:
         push eax
         mov eax,edx
         push eax
         call elementswap
         JMP L2
    
    L2:
        inc edi ;increment index innerloop
        JMP innerloop
     
    L3:
       inc esi
       JMP outerloop
       
    
    exit_loop:
    
    
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

bubblesort endp

main proc
push ebp
mov ebp,esp

    mov eax,OFFSET myarr
    push eax
    
    mov eax,LENGTHOF myarr 
    push eax
    
    call bubblesort
    
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
    
    invoke ExitProcess,0

main endp
end main
```

I am expecting 1,2,4,5,8 after calling bubblesort.

Comment: What did you get instead of your expected result?

Comment: Your `elementswap` function only swaps its args on the stack, not the pointed-to memory.  You should be passing it pointers (preferably in registers, or just inline it into the callee where you already have the pointer and values loaded; e.g. if you use `[edx]` and `[edx-4]` for two stores.

Comment: If the arguments are passed on the stack, one read of memory fetches the argument value, so a second read or write is necessary for the dereference.

Answer (score 2):

> In the swap function I passed the address of two elements that are supposed to swap.

Do you really? The code that invokes the *elementswap* looks like:

> ```
> push eax
> mov eax,edx
> push eax
> call elementswap
> ```

The first EAX that you push is the **value** of an array element, and the second EAX that you push is the **address** of another array element.
The C code is passing 2 addresses in `swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);`

> ```
> push eax
> push ebx
> ...
> pop eax
> pop ebx
> ```

In the *elementswap* proc you are trying to preserve the EAX and EBX registers on the stack. To restore these registers you need to reverse the `pop`'s:

```
push eax-----
push ebx--\  \ 
...        |  |
pop  ebx--/  /
pop  eax-----
```

> ```
> mov eax,[EBP+8] 
> mov ebx,[EBP+12]
> mov [EBP+8],ebx
> mov [EBP+12],eax
> ```

The *elementswap* proc is swapping its arguments (whatever they are) on the stack only and on the stack they stay because you never remove them! The stack will rapidly fill up this way and this can lead to stack/segmentation faults.

Because this is BubbleSort, swapping exclusively occurs between neighbouring array elements. Therefore a **single argument** (address) to the *elementswap* proc would be enough. And because after swapping is done, the argument is no longer needed, balance the stack by writing `ret 4`. This variation of the `ret` instruction adds 4 to the stackpointer upon returning to the caller.

```
elementswap proc
  push ebp
  mov  ebp, esp
  push eax
  push ebx
  mov  ebp, [ebp+8]    ; Stacked argument is address in between 2 array elements
  mov  eax, [ebp-4]    ; Element on the left
  mov  ebx, [ebp]      ; Element on the right
  mov  [ebp-4], ebx
  mov  [ebp], eax
  pop  ebx
  pop  eax
  pop  ebp
  ret  4               ; Removes stacked argument
elementswap endp
```

Your BubbleSort seems broken. eg. You exit immediately if the array contains 2 elements, but you start sorting if the array is empty or has but 1 element. To get it right, first study the example in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65143400/array-bubble-sort-in-assembly-language/65147578?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C25.9047#65147578) that I provided and then adapt it to your needs.

I understand that, for learning purposes, you do the swapping in a separate procedure, but a solution where the swapping is done inside the inner loop of the BubbleSort is more efficient.

Comment: Sometimes it *is* useful to pop registers in the wrong order intentionally, if for example you need to `xchg eax,ebx` after the `pop`s. But those situations are rare. If I'm doing so, I typically comment my code so that it's clear to anyone reading that it wasn't a typo.